# How to use the Offset() function when referencing the cell's tab/cell address

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2019

I am trying to use the Offset() function to return the value of a neighouring cell. Starting on the "Order" tab I would like to enter a cell reference ("source") to a "Ticker" code on the "static" tab and then reference the "Name" for this "Ticker" code which is the cell next to it.

The difficulty is that this "source" cell on the Order tab is a cell reference to another tab/cell. I am trying to achieve a level of "indirection" here by basing the other cell values on Order tab as an offset reference to this initial "source" cell reference. So for example if I decide to change the initial cell reference from "static!B5" (ie."IBM") to "static!B6" (ie. "MSFT") then the cells on Order tab next to this would all update automatically without me having to change them and would change the display value of "Name" from "International Business Machines" to "Microsoft"

Please see the following screenshots to help explain what I am trying to do.

**1. Static Tab** containing a list of Tickers and Names
[image]

**2. Order Tab** showing cell contents B5 which is a cell reference back to the Static tab
[image]

**3. Order Tab** showing cell contents C5
[image]

The formula in C5 doesn't work. I would like it to display "International Business Machines". Is anyone able to help please ?

UPDATE : I am using Excel version 2019

Comment: While your question is about how to use OFFSET, I think you really want to use a lookup function instead, like: `=VLOOKUP(B5,'Static'!B5:C6,2,0)`. This would be non-volatile and probably what you're really after.

Comment: No thats exactly what I am trying to avoid because the VLOOKUP forces you to arrange the source data in a particular way and I dont want that. I want to reference the first cell in my lookup data row but then be able to reference details of this data using an offset. The advantage is that I can then change the link to the source data and all the other cells using the offSet will update automatically. The answer I accepted below does what I was hoping.

Comment: If you insist. That makes your file slow, because OFFSET and INDIRECT are both volatile, meaning that all these will recalculate with any action in Excel. Even the change of selection triggers recalculation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/excel-recalculation#volatile-and-non-volatile-functions. Have you tried VLOOKUP? The idea is that you don't need your data to be in order, but lookup the string in the start column and return the value offset to the right of the start column.

Comment: check out Vlookup here. Change the value in `Static!B5` by choosing a different dropdown value: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AhxknrNHLDPCgYFlqznDgzelEswgPg?e=XWW0yc
I think you then understand the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FORMULATEXT to retrieve and parse the formula in the Ticker column (thanks @tnavidi).
Grab the formula, find the exclamation mark, use INDIRECT on everything to the right to get a reference, and apply OFFSET to find the neighboring cell.

`=OFFSET(INDIRECT("Static!"&MID(FORMULATEXT(B5),FIND("!",FORMULATEXT(B5))+1,99)),0,1)`

**Edit**
As MGonet remarked, this can be simplified because the original reference and the new reference both point to the same sheet. So there is no need to parses beyond the first `=`:

`=OFFSET(INDIRECT(MID(FORMULATEXT(B5),2,100)),0,1)`

Comment: The same a bit simpler:  
`=OFFSET(INDIRECT(MID(FORMULATEXT(B5),2,100)),0,1)`

Comment: Amazing that worked !! I used the Edit answer which @MGonet helped with. Thank you both thats really superb. I am not sure that I fully understand yet how it works but it does - so thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

you should do an `XLOOKUP` instead to the static tab, because you want to find the name based on the table on a different sheet.

```
=LET(static,Static!$C$5:$C$14,XLOOKUP(B5,static,OFFSET(static,0,1),"<not found>",0,1))
```

You need to adjust the number of rows in the static accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was hoping not to have to do a Lookup because I already know the starting row of the value I am interested in - I just need to be able to issue a relative offset reference to this starting cell

Comment: @robbie70 "I already know the starting row of the value I am interested in" - where is that information in your example data?

Comment: @robbie70, In that case I might have misunderstood your question. you could use `=OFFSET(Static!B5,0,1)`, if the rows on static and order are one to one, in which case you don't actually need offset at all, just use `=Static!C5` instead

Comment: @MátéJuhász the example is on the screenshot 2. In cell "order!B5" I am referencing the cell "static!B5" and in the cell  "order!B6" I would like to return the column value next to it ie. using something like Offset("static!B5,0,+1) i.e contents of "static!C5) goes into "order!C5"

Comment: @MátéJuhász I realise my question is a bit confusing but I am trying to achieve a level of "indirection" here where I just have one cell reference hard-coded and the other cell references are based on an offset of this one. The solutions you've presented above in your last comments all work fine but they are all based on me hardcoding the initial cell reference and I am trying to avoid this.

Comment: For example if I decided to change "IBM" to "MSFT" ie. change to "static!B6" then only this cell reference would change but all my other references next to it on the Order tab would automatically pick up the correct new values

Comment: You're effectively asking for a function which parses the formula in another cell, instead of the result. I don't think such a function exists, but you could make it through VBA. Alternatively, instead of putting the reference in the Ticker column, you could put it into a separate columns as text. Then both the Ticker column and Name column can be generated using INDIRECT and OFFSET. (Or, of course, you could use VLOOKUP instead :-)

Comment: @Paul "I don't think such a function exists" Actually there's a function `=FORMULATEXT`, but I don't think it's available in excel2019, and I lost track of what OP is actually trying to achieve.

Comment: @tnavidi, you are right, and it actually does exist for Excel2019 (according to Microsoft, I can't verify).